# How can I start a node/express server.js from Angular 5?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have an Angular App and want to start an Express Server (that runs on a different Port) from within my Angular Application. The Express Server is only a single server.js file that handles everything. I dont want it to start just by adding

```
node server.js
```

to the package.json, but instead to start it somehow in a Component or Service from the Angular App.
How would I accomplish that?

Comment: see this link: https://www.djamware.com/post/5a0673c880aca7739224ee21/mean-stack-angular-5-crud-web-application-example

Comment: @mintquan thanks that's a good link but it doesnt solve my specific scenario unfortunately